# Display a property of Objects in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a Ingredient class

```
public class Ingredient {
String NameP;
List ListS;
String Desc;
List ListT;
...
```

multiple instances of this class are stored in a Objects list.
I have also a

```
javax.swing.JList ListIng;
```

With it's model set to

```
ListIngModel = new DefaultListModel();
```

The idea is to use the Jlist to display the field "NameP" of all objects, select one of them to be further inspected and then grab the selected object:

```
Ingredient Selected = ListIngModel.get(ListIng.getSelectedIndex())
```

I can load the objects in the list model, but then the JList displays the address of those.
Is there an elegant way to make it display a property of the objects it stores?

Comment: Like a toString() method? I don't really follow the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make use the `JList`'s `CellRenderer`

Take a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details.

Basically, it allows you to define what the give object in the list model will appear like in the view.  This method allows you to customize the view as you need, even replacing it at run time.

**For Example**

```
public class IngredientListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                                 Object value,
                                 int index,
                                 boolean isSelected,
                                 boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof Ingredient) {
            Ingredient ingredient = (Ingredient)value;
            setText(ingredient.getName());
            setToolTipText(ingredient.getDescription());
            // setIcon(ingredient.getIcon());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that a JList allows you to select an item by entering the first character of the item. This functionality only works when the toString() method is implemented correctly. Using a renderer you lose this functionality.

Comment: @camickr That might not be to difficult to replicate with a little work - but it's good to know

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, that's what i was looking for. Care to elaborate a bit on the replication of the incremental search like camickr said?

Comment: @hater basically you would need some kind of "search model" that you could pass a string to and it would be capable of return 1 or more indices of objects that would match (based on the criteria of the search model). This process would require some kind of key listener to monitor key strokes and alter the search model of changes and highlight the items in the JList